# Playing a Sound Once

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How can I get sound to play once when the level changes in my game. Here is my current code,

```
_level = 1;
    if (_score >= 30
        ){
        _level = 2;
        [_levelLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level : %d", _level] ];
        [_levelLabel setColor:ccc3(152, 251, 152)];
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playEffect:@"effect"];
```

If the level changes the sound is played continuously, I would like it to only play once.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 levels then check if level == 1 before playing the sound and update the level to 2 only afterwards. I'd change to a more generic logic if you intend to have more levels though.

Comment: I have 12 levels, what is a good logic method to change and play a sound only upon changing levels.

Comment: @TheM00s3 in that case, have another variable, say _prevlevel, to save the previous level and update it to the value of _level only after playing the sound. So the new check becomes: if _level>_prevlevel then play the sound and set _prevlevel=_level